# Spring Boot conditional compilation/configuration

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have a Spring project that runs locally during the development/debugging phase, 
while on production it will be loaded on a PaaS.

My problem is that there are certain instruction that must be executed depending on the platform!

Currently I check a boolean (using `@ConfigurationProperties`) that I read from the `application.properties`, but I'm wondering if there's a smarter way because I have also to change the boolean when I push in production.

Comment: What kind of "instructions"? Do you mean configuration properties differ between envs or you need to execute some actual code depending on env?

Comment: You can try Spring profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Spring profiles and implement your check a little bit mor object oriented:

I assume your code looks something like this, and `Logic` is a spring managed bean:

```
@Component
public class Logic {
    public void doIt() {
        doMoreLogic();
        if (yourProperty == true) {
            your();
            certain();
            instructions();
        }
        doWhateverYouWant();
    }
}
```

If you extract the certain logic to a class, then you can do it more the object oriented way:

```
public interface PlatformDependentLogic {
    void platformInstructions();
}

@Component @Profile("dev")
public class DevLogic implements PlatformDependentLogic {
    public void platformInstructions() {
        your();
        certain();
        instructions();
    }
}
@Component @Profile("!dev")
public class NoopLogic implements PlatformDependentLogic {
    public void platformInstructions() {
        // noop
    }
}
```

Now you can reference the logic by doing this in your Logic bean:

```
@Component
public class Logic {
    private @Autowired PlatformDependentLogic platformLogic;
    public void doIt() {
        doMoreLogic();
        platformLogic.platformInstructions();
        doWhateverYouWant();
    }
}
```

Of course you can utilize the spring boot specific `@ConditionalOnProperty` instead of the `@Profile` annotation like this:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="your.property", hasValue="dev")
```

To get a better understanding of this annotation and how it workds you should read the [official documentation of `@ConditionalOnProperty`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using Gradle product flavors for your local/Paas environments, something similar to this:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-gradle-build-variants--cms-25005